# Why does the 'in' operator recognize substrings but not sublists?

Tags: python

Why is this true:

```
'bcd' in 'abcde'
```

But this is false:

```
[2,3,4] in [1,2,3,4,5]
```

These statements are conceptually identical, are they not?  Does the `in` operator have special rules for strings?

Comment: `in` tests for elements. [2, 3, 4] must be an element

Comment: `str.__contains__` is just weird like that, because someone figured it was useful back in Python's early days, probably pre-1.0. It *is* more useful than an elementhood check for strings, but it's still a weird exception.

Comment: @mamun: It usually tests for elements, but that's not what it does with strings.

Comment: Each class can define its own `__contains__`.

Answer (score 4):

A list can be contained inside a list.

```
[[2, 3, 4], 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

in which iterating over the outer list one element at a time

```
[2,3,4] in [[2, 3, 4], 3, 4, 5]
```

gives you a `True` value

There is no equivalent for a string for this type of situation.

You can make a new type by subclassing list and changing the `__contains__` as @hpaulj pointed out.

But here are some questions before you begin?

How many times would you expect to find [2,3,4] in this?

```
[[2, 3, 4], 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

or this

```
[[2,3,4], [2],[3],[4],5]
```

Comment: In effect the concept of a sublist is poorly defined, while we all know what a substring is.

Answer (score 0):

*Review*

Let's look at the left/right superset data structures and their elements:

```html
|           Example           | Structure | Element |
|-----------------------------|-----------|---------|
|  'bcd'     in    'abcde'    | str       | str     |
|  [0, 1, 2] in [0, 1, 2, 3]  | list      | int     |
```

I suspect the principle is as follows:

- When data structure and element types are equivalent, `in` comparison is clear, e.g. a substring of a string.
- When data structure and element types are not equivalent, `in` is ambiguous.

Let's look closer at this ambiguity.

*Discussion*

Given

```
[0, 1, 2] in [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

are we comparing

1. containers of elements (default)?
2. just elements alone?

If using approach 2 where `in` solely compares elements, then

```
[0, 1, 2] in [0, 1, 2, 3]
(0, 1, 2) in [0, 1, 2, 3]
{0, 1, 2} in [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

should each return `True` since `0, 1, 2` are elements shared in left and right containers.  Such comparisons disregard the container type.  This approach limits `in`, especially since element comparison can done with sets:

```
set([0, 1, 2]) < set([0, 1, 2, 3])
# True

set([0, 1, 2]).issubset([0, 1, 2, 3])
# True
```

*Summary*

1. Leave container + element comparisons to `in`
2. Leave strict element comparisons to `set()`